# Benefit of composition functions

Tags: php, oop, composition, single-responsibility-principle

I have four *methods* which alter the input and return the output.

```
class edit
{

    function a($input) { return $input + 4; }
    function b($input) { return $input - 2; }
    function c($input) { return $input * 10; }
    function d($input) { return $input / 8; }

}
```

Coincidentally these *methods* need to be called one after the other with the returned output from the previous as the input to the next.

We can handle this process multiple ways.

```
$handle = new edit();

$output = $handle->a(8);
$output = $handle->b($output);
$output = $handle->c($output);
$output = $handle->d($output);
```

or

create another *method* within the class to handle this entire procedure.

```
function all($input)
{
    $output = $this->a($input);
    $output = $this->b($output);
    $output = $this->c($output);
    $output = $this->d($output);
    return $output;
}

$handle = new edit(8);

$handle->all();
```

These both achieve the same task.

However, I have recently learned about **composition functions**, Which is perfect for I need to achieve.

(note for the example here I have moved the *methods a,b,c,d* from the *class* and will call them as *functions* in a *procedural* manor, I have been unable to make this **composition function** OOP friendly, please excuse me for this.)

```
function compose($f,$g,$h,$i) 
{
    return function($x) use ($f, $g, $h, $i) { return $f($g($h($i($x)))); };
}

$comp = compose('a', 'b','c','d');
$result = $comp(8);
```

With all this being said, I want to know the benefit of achieving this task with the **composition function**?

I can only notice minimal improvement in that we do not have to pass the input four times, only once.

In my recent research, I have come across multiple software engineers talking about how great functional programming is.

I feel that I am missing something? Or is the only improvement what I mentioned?

PS - The language I use is PHP, The methods/functions I gave here are just simple examples to illustrate the point. I am also trying to adhere to **SOLID** principles.

Thanks.